# N'importe quoi n'importe quand

Tags: traduction, pronoms, négation

> Do not do everything anytime!

Comment peut-on traduire cela? Peut-être

> Ne fais pas n'importe quoi n'importe quand !

Je n'aime pas cette phrase, mais je ne sais pas comment traduire autrement.

Comment: “Do not do everything anytime!” isn't clear. What context do you have in mind?

Comment: I'm sorry, I know it doesn't really make much sense, but it's a sentence I have to translate for school without any other context :( I don't like it either. I think it should be something like an imperative, smb is always making (probably) a mess and you scold him by saying "don't make everything (all the mess you're doing) anytime (always)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La traduction que tu proposes :

> Ne fais pas n'importe quoi n'importe quand.

me semble relativement juste et assez fidèle à la version anglaise de départ.
On pourrait éventuellement lui préférer

> Ne fais pas tout à n'importe quel moment.

**Cependant, dans les deux langues**, elle est troublante et a un sens assez peu clair... ce qui constitue probablement un problème pour arriver à une traduction satisfaisante.

(Quel est le sens que l'on veut véhiculer ici ? *Ne fais pas chaque chose de manière intempestive* ? ou bien... *Ne fais pas tout et n'importe quoi* indépendamment de la notion de temps ? Sans plus de contexte c'est difficile à deviner.)

Answer (score 2):

> Ne fais pas tout tout le temps !

Cela ressemble aux deux affirmations dans la langue d'origine.

Answer (score 0):

I think the expression

> Il y a un temps pour chaque chose.

is the best traduction.

Comment: *La meilleure traduction* me semble un peu péremptoire en l'occurrence dans la mesure où la phrase originale est un ordre/conseil (forme impérative) alors que ta traduction la transforme une assertion. Mais cela dit on y retrouve un sens assez proche, c'est juste.

Comment: Quel terme de la réponse "I think" ne comprenez-vous pas ?
En disant cela, mon interlocuteur est sensé comprendre que 
ce que j'affirme est mon opinion propre.

Comment: Comme je comprends effectivement *I think*, j'émets un avis qui nuance en partie votre propos. Si vous n'êtes pas d'accord, il existe une solution simple : argumentez sur le sujet et défendez votre 'opinion propre' au lieu de nous la servir toute nue. S'il vous plait.